# Custom Taxonomy term archive template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

Is it possible to have separate archive templates for custom taxonomies?

Like this:

Tax(categories)

-Players(category)

-Managers(category)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the heirarchy is like this:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
taxonomy.php
archive.php
index.php
```

So in your case you would create:

taxonomy-tax-players.php
and
taxonomy-tax-managers.php

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have separate archive templates for custom taxonomies?

Yes. Each file name depends on the slug for that taxonomy. See the [Custom Taxonomies display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) section of the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for specifics.